# Workaround for NAT only in Virtualbox using Kali linux

Tags: virtualbox, nat

I'm using a Kali on a Virtualbox inside a corporate laptop, I can't use bridged mode so Im stuck with NAT, the issue that I cannot access this kali vm from other assets in the network, as it has a different IP that's available only for the host itself, so my question is there any way with ssh tunneling maybe to make the Kali vm reachable from other laptops in the network ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use NAT mode, then you'll need to [configure a port forwarding in VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) so that connections to a chosen port on the host's IP address will be redirected to the guest's SSH port (22/TCP).

Note that being restricted to the NAT mode will heavily limit what you can do with Kali's penetration testing and network auditing tools. If you are using Kali as a general-purpose Linux desktop installation, you should be aware that [even the makers of Kali themselves recommend **not** using it for that use case.](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)